# Define "display" css property upon jQuery/JS toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, toggle, display

I'm toggling between two `divs` with jQuery (I'm new to jQuery...) and I want both `divs` to use the `display: flex` property. I'm able to assign it to the first/default toggle (Option 1), but the second toggle (Option 2) defaults to `display: block`, and I'm not sure how to hook onto that.

Any insight would be so helpful - thanks!

Here's a jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/fZemQ/97/

**HTML**

```
<div class="pricing-switcher">
    <a class="toggle active" id="HS-College">High School and College</a>
    <a class="toggle" id="Club-Youth">Club and Youth</a>
</div>

<div class="pricing-wrapper">
    <div class="panels HS-College">Option 1 Option 1 Option 1 Option 1 Option 1 Option 1 Option 1 Option 1 Option 1</div>
    <div class="panels Club-Youth">Option 2 Option 2 Option 2 Option 2 Option 2 Option 2 Option 2 Option 2 Option 2</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.panels {
    display: none;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.panels.HS-College {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.panels.Club-Youth {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}    

.pricing-switcher {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}

.toggle {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    margin-right: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.toggle.active {
    background-color: red;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.toggle').click(function(){
        var self = $(this);    
        $('.panels').hide();    
        if(self.hasClass('active') ) {
            self.removeClass('active');
            $('.panels.HS-College').fadeIn();
        }else{
            $('.toggle').removeClass('active');
            self.addClass('active');
            $('.panels.'+ self.attr('id')).fadeIn();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not assigning the css to the other panel. So it has default block display.

```
.panels.HS-College, .panels.Club-Youth {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

here is the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6n0zfdnd/

Answer (score 0):

A little tough to say if this is what you are looking for, but try merging these two rules:

```
.panels {
    display: none;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.panels.HS-College {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

into one rule:

```
.panels {
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `AddClass` and `RemoveClass` you can simply call:

```
.toggleClass()
```

Jquery Ref here:
http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Which will remove the class if existing and add if not.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you to solve the problem...

In your CSS file Add below property for `Club-Youth` div class also...add this code snippet to your CSS.

```
.panels.Club-Youth {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

And the resultant CSS code will be...

```
.panels {
    display: none;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.panels.HS-College {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.panels.Club-Youth {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.pricing-switcher {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}

.toggle {
    float: left;
    display: flex;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    margin-right: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.toggle.active {
    background-color: red;
}
```